# set up redirection in 51 degrees asp.net library

Tags: asp.net, razor, 51degrees

I am an ASP.NET developer. I am developing a website for which I need redirection to my mobile pages for mobile devices. Currently, I have pages suffixed with .mobile & using default asp.net razor webpages redirection but it is outdated so i want to set up 51 degrees library to redirect to .mobile pages 
Currently I have tried Using forking with Settings Which Visual Studio Adds automatically with no success

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share with us what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi, have you tried following the steps from 51Degrees documentation: https://51degrees.com/support/documentation/net/webapplications/mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "IsMobile" property from the 51Degrees library and the re-direct to your .mobile page if the property is true. Can you show me a sample of the code?